# App does not register custom button clicks

Tags: java, android, button

I am having a problem with one of my applications.  I have written a basic application menu which has custom buttons linking to other activity's.  My problem is that it seems my application is not registering my button clicks when I am testing it.  I do not receive any errors or crashes upon clicks, the application just acts as if the click never happened. Could anyone provide me with any help with this problem, I have provided some code bellow.

Main Menu code:

```
public void initialize(){

    Film = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFilm);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try{
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.bFilm:
        Intent film = new Intent(this, Film.class);
        startActivity(film);
        break;
```

Layout Code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFilm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:background="@drawable/film"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Custom XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/actor_1"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/actor_1"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/actor_1"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your initialize(), add after `findViewById` the following:

```
Film.setOnClickListener(onClick);
```

Comment: Oh wow, Even I didn't think I was bad enough to miss that out, Thank you this fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
android:onclick="onClick"
```

in

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFilm"
android:onclick="onClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/film"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

it will work
**EDIT**
However 
`onClick` attribute is not defined for API 3 and less. (Android <= 1.5)

It works since API 4 (Android 1.6)

If you want compatibility you can use:

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply however in my XML I get the error: No Resource found for OnClick in android

Comment: you might be using api less than 4 that why i have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, But I had forgot the onclicklistener that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void initialize(){

Film = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFilm);
Film.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```